# You tell on me, I tell on you

Tags: phrase-request, conditional-constructions

Dialogue:

> — Don't even think about going out.
>   — Why? I'll tell mom you broke a glass.
>   — **You tell on me, I tell on you**.
>   — What? I'm clean. I didn't do anything!

Is the bolded expression widely used? Is there a way to rephrase it?

Comment: I think this is more commonly used.. ***"If you tell on me then I will tell on you"***

Comment: The phrase "tell on" can also be replaced by the synonym *tattle*: _"If you tattle on me, then I'll tattle on you."_ When children are speaking, though, I believe _tell on_ is much more widely used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a common pattern. **If** and **will** are not necessary in this "tit for tat" colloquial construction.

P.S. You can probably find it in a Scorsese film.  These are words we'd expect DeNiro to say.

Answer (score 2):

> (If) you tell on me, I **'ll** tell on you

You need to add the **will** since it is a future threat.
The expression is used by **children**, since **telling on** or **being told on** is an action that usually happens with children, and **yes** it is still in common usage. Although it can be used with adults, there are other words which describe the grown-up version:

> **report**
>   **rat on**
>   **notify**

Your example is a form of a **tit-for-tat** game

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use the second one without *will.*

Comment: @Subjunctive Maybe without **will** it's a jargonized, colloquialized form; reflecting the way the words are pronounced  - in order to impart the feeling of authenticity.

Comment: I'm sure it does get used without the *will*, and there is an implicit *if* which was not used in the example. **You tell on me, I tell on you** sounds more like **you drink your soda, and I drink my soda**, a statement of action. I'm pretty sure kids would never mean to say they **should both tell on each other**. Not many kids I know are familiar with agreed **Mutually Assured Destruction** :)

Comment: No, you don't need to add *will*.